# javax.Servlet interface does not exist

Tags: java, servlets

Currently I am reading the book "Java Concurrency in Practice". One of the very first examples is this piece of code:

```
public class StatelessFactorizer implements Servlet {
///someMethod
}
```

I wanted to follow this example but could not write it in eclipse as the interface Servlet seems to be missing.

To be more specific, eclipse gives me this message:

```
Servlet cannot be resolved to a type
```

After searching the web I learned that there is a `javax.servlet.Servlet` interface, but I could not find it nor employ it/import it in/to my code.

Moreover, every resource I found thus far connects this interface with the Tomcat server, but all I want is to follow the book example!

I must also admit that I know nothing about servlets yet...

So my question, dear experts, is:

How to "teach" eclipse about the `Servlet interface` so it will acknowledge its existence?

I am using Linux ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS,  eclipse version 2019-03 (4.11.0), java-8-openjdk-amd64

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It isn't part of Java SE. So you need to add the library containing it to your deendencies: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api. But that will only allow you to compile the code. If you actually plan to create a webapp and run it into a server, you really need to learn about servlets, by reading a book or a tutorial.

Comment: @JB Nizet thanks for your comment. I followed your link but did not understand how to do what you are suggesting. how do I add the library containing it to my dependencies?

Comment: If you use a build tool like Maven or Gradle, by adding the coordinates of the library to the dependencies. If not, by downloading the jar, and adding it to the build path of your Eclipse project. Being able to use libraries is quite fundamental stuff, whereas concurrency is quite advanced and very complex. You should probably start by learning the basics.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks. I also appreciate your comment. Problem is that I am following a course curriculum and concurrency is the topic at hand...truth is I was not aware that there are other things that need to be added to eclipse or build path. Thanks for your help!